# Inno Setup Count files in a directory with given file extension

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I wanted to count files in a directory with a given file extension in Inno Setup. I wrote the following code.

Regards,

```pascal
function AmountOfFilesInDir(const DirName, Extension: String): Integer;
var
  FilesFound: Integer;
  ShouldBeCountedUppercase, ShouldBeCountedLowercase: Boolean;
  FindRec: TFindRec;
begin
  FilesFound := 0;
  if FindFirst(DirName, FindRec) then begin
    try
      repeat
        if (StringChangeEx(FindRec.Name, Lowercase(Extension), Lowercase(Extension), True) = 0) then
          ShouldBeCountedLowercase := False
        else
          ShouldBeCountedLowercase := True;
        if (StringChangeEx(FindRec.Name, Uppercase(Extension), Uppercase(Extension), True) = 0) then
          ShouldBeCountedUppercase := False
        else
          ShouldBeCountedUppercase := True;
        if (FindRec.Attributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 0)
           and ((ShouldBeCountedUppercase = True) or (ShouldBeCountedLowercase = True)) then begin
          FilesFound := FilesFound + 1;
        end;
      until not FindNext(FindRec);
    finally
      FindClose(FindRec);
    end;
  end;
  Result := FilesFound;
end;
```

And an usage example can be:

```
Log(IntToStr(AmountOfFilesInDir(ExpandConstant('{sys}\*'), '.exe')));
```

I like to reduce the lines in this function's code to make it look more professional as it looks bit long. I need to know how can I do it without failing this function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`FindFirst` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_findfirst) can select the files based on wildcard (extension) on its own:

```pascal
function AmountOfFiles(PathWithMask: string): Integer;
var
  FindRec: TFindRec;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if FindFirst(PathWithMask, FindRec) then
  begin
    try
      repeat
        Inc(Result);
      until not FindNext(FindRec);
    finally
      FindClose(FindRec);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Use it like:

```pascal
Log(IntToStr(AmountOfFiles(ExpandConstant('{sys}\*.exe'))));
```